# Laravel User will have difference Role base on Project Model

Tags: laravel

I have Model name **Project** and **User** by using laravel relationship.
- **project** and **user** using **many to many relationship**.
What i want is using laravel authentication **giving roles** to the **user** base on **project**.
Which mean :
user "**Ali**" have role "**admin**" in project "**project a**" , 
but in project "**project b**" the user "**Ali**" role is "**member**".
How can i implement it?

**Problem fixed :**

My solution is add additional data inside the `project_users` pivot table store as string `role`.
When create new project and add with additional data using :

```
$user->projects()->save($project, ['role' => 'Manager']);
```

When need to call it :

```
$user_role = $user->projects()->where('user_id', $user['id'])->first()->pivot->role;
```

It will return a string `'Manager'`
and use it to assign the role.

```
$user->syncRoles($user_role);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the **Role** data e.g. `role_id` with a separate Role table or just `role` in Project To User Pivot Table `project_users` and retrieve the role info from this relationship.

Check out this **Saving Additional Data On A Pivot Table** section at [Update Many To Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) Laravel Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following links which will help you to achieve it.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html

Comment: example can't run properly so i not sure it can solve my problem or not.